# Encountering errors when realizing download method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I encountered a weird problem when realizing the download method.
It works fine on most of browsers. But when testing it on chrome, chrome automatically changed the url to:

```
https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fnew_admin%2Fquestion_sets%2F105%2Fexport.xls
```

when it should be:

```
http://my.domain.whatever/new_admin/question_sets/105/export.xls.
```

What's weirder, this problem only occurs after left cliking the link. If you middle-clicks the link, it still works. I can't figure out the reason.

This is my relative controller's code:

```
respond_to do |format| 
  format.xls {send_data(to_xls(@question_set), :type=>:xls, :filename => "question_set_#{@question_set.id}.xls")}
end
```

This is the haml code of the button:

```
<%= link_to "export",export_new_admin_question_set_path(:format => 'xls',:id => set.id),:class=>"delete",:target => "_blank" %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it happens only in Chrome, it could be due to a Chrome extension perhaps intercepting the download. I looked around and it seems there are a few extensions that do this. [Here's one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/docs-pdfpowerpoint-viewer/nnbmlagghjjcbdhgmkedmbmedengocbn/details?hl=en). Is there a chance that you have one of these installed?

It's also possible that the middle click opens a new tab in which case the download goes ahead normally (some of the extension's reviews mention that).